# Half my model isn't flipping correctly and the other half isn't flipping at all

Tags: modeling, animation, mirror, mixamo

i'm new to blender, but i really wanted to learn so i've been working on a walk cycle for a model i imported from Mixamo:[image] (please excuse the extra armatures that came with it i will remove them)
I understand the process of how to make a walk cycle and i've already attempted to make a contact pose, so now i need to flip the model in the middle, so i selected my whole model and copied pose and then on the 13th frame i selected paste flipped and it came out like this:[image]
I tried using ctrl+m and then x-axis. It works perfectly however it affects the original contact pose on frame 1 and 24, I'm not sure how to fix it and even why it doesn't work in the first place, so any advice i would gladly appreciate. Here is the blender file for it, in case it helps:https://1drv.ms/u/c/7d12f10b0f64059b/EXt6ye5upP9AleqyFNWiO6UBsfbbMgjSzfO3MxMUntz5sg?e=X7GRz7
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, it asks for a password, please use another platform

Comment: Oh no I do apologise, my laptop is the only device I have for this

Comment: Please use [here](https://blend-exchange.com). @moonboots is required to notify him.